# Making Responsive Tabs in Boostrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive design in bootstrap3. 
I want to modify my template design for tabs. And for that I am using a external js file.

For now I am planning to show them in only desktop version. I am not sure how to have same kind of effect in mobile. SO for now just dektop.

When I am integrating with Bootstrap3 responsive its not working. 
 However with a plain html file without bootstrap code its working fine.

Would anyone be able to help me to achieve this using Bootstrap3?

```
I have added the code in js fiddle @
http://jsfiddle.net/monicaRegal/do5b3ko3/1/
```

[image]

Thank You
Regards,
Monica Mandal

Comment: So what exactly are you wanting that involves Bootstrap? Are you wanting the tabs to be responsive with the rest of the page, unlike what's in your fiddle, which isn't?

Comment: Yes I want tabs to be responsive with the map images. On click of tabs the map image color should change and look and feel should be the same as in my jsFiddle

Comment: Well bootstrap tabs should be responsive outright, but how responsive they are depends on the width of the container you put them in, as well as other items you may add to your CSS/JavaScript to affect that. See my solution bellow for tabs that span the whole width of the page. You should be able to style them from there to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're needing tabs made with Bootstrap to expand to the full width of the page or their container, use the `nav-justified` class in your markup.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

Body Content Here
<br />
<br />

<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">The Americas</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Europe</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Middle East/Africa</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Asia/Pacific</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">The Americas content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Europe content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Middle East/Africa content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Asia/Pacific content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can then style your tabs however you need. View the snippet in full page mode to see it properly.

Comment: Thanks MattD. I am able to achieve this but not able to add small map images. Please help on that.

Comment: That's a styling matter, and a separate question unrelated to getting responsive tabs.